# ¿Cómo imprimir una matriz en forma de tablero por consola en Java?

Tags: java

estoy haciendo el juego [Timbiriche](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timbiriche_(juego)#:%7E:text=Timbiriche%2C%20colch%C3%B3n%20%2C%20cuadrito%2C%20cajas,tener%20una%20fuerte%20componente%20estrat%C3%A9gica.), y estoy teniendo problemas para imprimir el tablero del juego, el tamaño puede ser desde 2x2 hasta 10x10 (el jugador lo escoge) todo esto tiene que ser utilizando matrices.

Todo el proceso para crear la matriz se hace correctamente, el problema que tengo es directamente a la hora de imprimir el tablero y que quede acomodado correctamente.

De igual manera voy a mostrar resumidamente el proceso que llevo porque creo que si no puede ser un poco confuso.

Para crearlo hice una clase Tablero, con sus respectivos setters y getters.

```
public class Tablero {
    private int alturaTablero;
    private int anchuraTablero;
    boolean marcaArriba;
    boolean marcaAbajo;
    boolean marcaIzquierda;
    boolean marcaDerecha;
    boolean cuadroCerrado;
   
    public Tablero (boolean marcaArribaN, boolean marcaAbajoN, boolean marcaIzquierdaN, boolean marcaDerechaN, boolean cuadroCerradoN){
        this.marcaArriba = marcaArribaN;
        this.marcaAbajo = marcaAbajoN;
        this.marcaIzquierda = marcaIzquierdaN;
        this.marcaDerecha = marcaDerechaN;
        this.cuadroCerrado = cuadroCerradoN;
    }
    //no incluí setters&getters en la pregunta
}
```

En la clase main, tengo éste método que es el encargado de iniciar la matriz con los valores iniciales.
(el tamaño se le asigna a la matriz en la clase del JFrame en el que se pregunta el tamaño del tablero al usuario (desde 2x2, hasta 10x10))

```
static Tablero t[][];
    public void iniciarJuego(int alturaT, int anchuraT){
        for (int i=0;i<alturaT;i++){
            for (int j=0;j<anchuraT;j++){
                t[i][j] = new Tablero(false,false,false,false,false);
                tableroCreado=true;
            }
        }
        
        InterfazGrafica inGraf = new InterfazGrafica();
       // inGraf.imprimirPuntaje();
        inGraf.imprimirTablero();
    }
}
```

Y por último, tengo la clase InterfazGrafica, que es desde donde quiero imprimir mi tablero a través de la matriz t[][] de la clase main.

```
public class InterfazGrafica {
    
    public InterfazGrafica(){
    }
    public void imprimirTablero(){
        System.out.println("Tablero de: "+Juego.t.length+"x"+Juego.t[0].length);

        for(int x=0;x<ConfiguracionJuego.alturaTableroJ;x++){
            for(int y=0;y<ConfiguracionJuego.anchuraTableroJ;y++){
                
                //Marcas de Arriba
                
                if(Juego.t[x][y].marcaArriba==true) {
                    if (y==(Juego.t[x].length-1)){
                        System.out.print("*¯¯*");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("*¯¯");
                    }
                } else {
                    if (y==(Juego.t[x].length-1)){
                        System.out.print("*  *");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("*  ");
                }
                }
                
                //Marcas de izquierda y derecha
                
                if(Juego.t[x][y].marcaIzquierda==true && Juego.t[x][y].marcaDerecha==true){
                    if(y==(Juego.t[x].length-1)){
                        System.out.println("|  |");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("|  |");
                    }
                }
                
                if (Juego.t[x][y].marcaIzquierda==true && Juego.t[x][y].marcaDerecha==false) {
                    if(y==(Juego.t[x].length-1)){
                        System.out.println("|   ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("|   ");
                    }
                }
                
                if (Juego.t[x][y].marcaIzquierda==false && Juego.t[x][y].marcaDerecha==true) {
                    if(y==(Juego.t[x].length-1)){
                        System.out.println("   |");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("   |");
                    }
                }
                
                if (Juego.t[x][y].marcaIzquierda==false && Juego.t[x][y].marcaDerecha==false) {
                    if(y==(Juego.t[x].length-1)){
                        System.out.println("    ");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("    ");
                    }
                }
                
                //Marcas de abajo
                if (Juego.t[x][y].marcaAbajo==true){
                    if(y==(Juego.t[x].length-1)) {
                        System.out.print("___*");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("____");
                    }
                } else {
                    if (y==(Juego.t[x].length-1)){
                        System.out.print("*   *");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print("*    ");
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }        
    } //fin metodo
}
```

La idea que tuve para imprimir el tablero era hacerlo en orden; Arriba > (salto de linea) > Izquierda - Derecha > (salto de linea) > Abajo.

Imaginaba una salida así: (para un tablero 3x3, y con el juego ya avanzado, por ejemplo)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en vez de eso estoy obteniendo esta salida, en un tablero 3x3 y el juego sin iniciar aún.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias. Acepto Cualquier tipo de sugerencia/consejo que puedan darme.

Answer (score 1):

Es un problema complejo. Te recomiendo cambiar totalmente de estrategia, principalmente porque no consigo entender tu código, y tampoco se me ocurre como hacerlo según tu metodo de out.println en una iteración doble.

Lo que si se me ocurre es usar un char[][] a modo de canvas. Este metodo parece que se presta mejor a estructurar y hacer tests mejor.

Para n>1 el tamaño es (n*4)-1

```
public static char[][] emptyTimbiriche(int n) {
    int size = n * 4 - 1;
    var empty = new char[size][size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            empty[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
    return empty;
}
```

Esto es demasiado simple, y no hace falta test. Lo siguiente seria poner los vertices. Estos estan en la posición 0,3,6.. de las filas 0,3,6... humm, parece que hay un patrón

```
   public static void putVertex(char[][] t, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n+1; j++) {
                t[i*3][j*3] = '*';
            }
        }
    }
```

Y una función para pasar de array a String ya que System.out no entiende char[][]

```
public static String arrayToString(char[][] t) {
    var sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
        sb.append(t[i]).append('\n');
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Esto ya tiene pinta de necesitar un test para asegurar que lo estamos haciendo bien

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TimbiTest {

    // @formatter:off
    String tal = "*  *  *  *\n"
               + "          \n"
               + "          \n"
               + "*  *  *  *\n"
               + "          \n"
               + "          \n"
               + "*  *  *  *\n"
               + "          \n"
               + "          \n"
               + "*  *  *  *\n"
    // @Formatter: on


    @Test
    public void testVertexs() {
        var t = Timbiriche.emptyTimbiriche(3);
        Timbiriche.putVertex(t, 3);
        String s = Timbiriche.arrayToString(t);
        assertEquals(tal, s);
    }

}
```

Parece que me he equivocado en algo, pero por lo menos tenemos una bonita ventana que nos dice la diferencia:

[image: bonita ventana]

Ahora puedes hacer un tablero con una linea, "pintarla" en el array y comprobar que está donde debe, luego 2 lineas... y como tienes los tests sabes que lo que hagas no rompe lo conseguido hasta ese punto.

Answer (score 0):

Este código hicimos en grupo estero que sirva para futuras búsquedas:

es complejo pero espero que ayude

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Mmsystem.h>

using namespace std;

void pantalla();
void menu();
struct valores_retorno matrizlogica(char i1,char j1);
void regist();
int validar_cadena(string cadena);
void titulo();
void escribirArchivo();
void leerArchivo(string opcion);

void pausa() {
    string r;
    fflush(stdin);
    cout << "presiona cualquier tecla para continuar" << endl;
    getline(cin,r);
}

struct valores_retorno{
    int iout,jout;
};

struct datos{
    string nombre;
    long int puntos;
};
datos *fichas = new datos[10];

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main(){
    menu();
    return 0;
}

void menu(){
    int opcion;
  titulo();
  do{
  system("cls");
    cout << "\t\t\t\t\t TORTUNTITOS" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "\t 1. Jugar" << endl;
    cout << "\t 2. Tabla de Puntuaciones" << endl;
    cout << "\t 3. Creditos" << endl;
    cout << "\t 4. Resetear" << endl;
    cout << "\t 5. Salir" << endl;
    cin >> opcion;
    switch(opcion){
    case 1:{
      system("cls");
      cout << "\t\t\t\t\t TORTUNTITOS" << endl;
      cout << "--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
      cout << "\t\tRegistro de datos" << endl;
      cout << "Ingresar los nombres de los jugadores" << endl;
      regist();
      system("cls");
      pantalla();
      pausa();
      break;
    }
    case 2:{
      system("cls");
      cout << "\t\tTabla de Puntuaciones" << endl;
      cout << "\t--------------------------------------" << endl;
      cout << "\tNombre\t\t||\tPuntuacion" << endl;
      leerArchivo("TabladePuntuaciones.txt");
      pausa();
      break;
    }
    case 3:{
      system("cls");
      cout << "\t\t\tCreditos" << endl;
      cout << "\t-----------------------------------------------------" << endl;
      leerArchivo("Creditos.txt");
      pausa();
      break;
    }
    case 4:{
      system("cls");
      ofstream archivo;
      archivo.open("TabladePuntuaciones.txt",ios::trunc);
      archivo.close();
      break;
    }
    case 5:{
      system("cls");
      cout << "Saliste del juego....." << endl;
      break;
    }
    default:
      cout << "Opcion no valida" << endl;
      pausa();
      break;
    }
    }while(opcion!=5);
}

void regist(){
  int sw=0, i=0;
    string nombre;

    for(i; i<2; i++){
        cout << "Jugador " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> fichas[i].nombre;
        sw = validar_cadena(fichas[i].nombre);
    if(sw==1){
      if(i==0){
      i=-1;
      }else if(i==1){
        i=0;
      }
        }
  }
}

int validar_cadena(string cadena){
  string simbolo = "0123456789";
  int i=0, sw=0, j;
  j=cadena.length();
  while(i<j && sw==0){
    if(isalpha(cadena[i])!=0){
      sw==0;
      i++;
    }else{
      cout << "Nombre Incorrecto" << endl;
      sw=1;
    }
  }
  return sw;
}

struct valores_retorno matrizlogica(char i1,char j1){
    int matriz[21][21]={};
    char posicionletra[11]={'0','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};
    char posicionnumero[10]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    valores_retorno valores;
    int iout,jout,confirm;

    //lineas de la tabla valor=1;
    do{
    for(jout=0;jout<=10;jout++){
        for(iout=0;iout<=10;iout++){
            if((i1==posicionletra[jout] && j1==posicionnumero[iout]) || (i1==posicionnumero[jout] && j1==posicionletra[iout])){
                if(i1==posicionletra[jout]){
                    matriz[iout*2][jout*2-1]=1;
                    valores.iout=iout;
                    valores.jout=jout;
                    confirm=1;
                }else{
                    matriz[iout*2-1][jout*2]=1;
                    valores.iout=iout;
                    valores.jout=jout;
                    confirm=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }while(confirm=0);
    return valores;
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*Funcion para mostrar pantalla de juego*/
void pantalla(){
    char matriz[84][42]={};
    for(int j=0;j<=20;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<=39;i++){
        matriz[i][j]=' ';
        }}

    char numeracion[20]={'0','a','1','b','2','c','3','d','4','e','5','f','6','g','7','h','8','i','9','j'};
    char posicionletra[10]={'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};
    char posicionnumero[10]={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};
    char posicionletral[11]={'0','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};
    char i1,j1;
    valores_retorno valores,v;
    int matrizl[21][21]={};
    int puntaje1=0,puntaje2=0;

    for(int j=0;j<=18;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<=39;i++){
            //Guias de posicionamiento en el tablero
            if(i%8==0 && j%4==0 && i<80 && j<39){
                    matriz[i][j+2]=posicionletra[j/4];
            }
            if(i%8==1 && j%4==0 && i<80 && j<39){
                    matriz[i][j+2]=posicionnumero[i/8];
            }
            if(i%8==0 && j%4==0 && i<80 && j<39){
                    matriz[i+4][j]=posicionnumero[j/4];
            }
            if(i%8==1 && j%4==0 && i<80 && j<39){
                    matriz[i+4][j]=posicionletra[i/8];
            }}}

    for(int k=0;k<20;k++){
        for(int j=0;j<=19;j++){
            for(int i=0;i<=41;i++){
                if(matriz[i][j]=='\0'){
                    matriz[i][j]=' ';
                }
                //lineas horizontales superior e inferior
                matriz[i][0]=219;
                matriz[i][20]=219;
                //lineas verticales (1)(2) izquierda (3)(4) derecha
                matriz[0][j]=219;//(1)
                matriz[1][j]=219;//(2)
                matriz[41][j]=219;//(3)
                matriz[40][j]=219;//(4)
                //cuadros o puntos del tablero
                if(i%8==0 && j%4==0 && i<80 && j<39){
                    matriz[i][j]=219;
                }
                if(i%8==1 && j%4==0 && i<80 && j<39){
                    matriz[i][j]=219;
                }
                //lineas de juego (hechas por jugador)
                int vertical=0,horizontal=0;
                for(int k=0;k<10;k++){if(i1==posicionletra[k]){vertical=1;}}
                for(int k=0;k<10;k++){if(i1==posicionnumero[k]){horizontal=1;}}
                if((i==valores.iout*8 || i==valores.iout*8+1 ) && j==valores.jout*4-2 && vertical==1){
                    matriz[i][j-1]=176;
                    matriz[i][j]=176;
                    matriz[i][j+1]=176;
                }
                if((i==valores.iout*8-4 || i==valores.iout*8-3) && j==valores.jout*4 && horizontal==1){
                    matriz[i-2][j]=176;
                    matriz[i][j]=176;
                    matriz[i+2][j]=176;
                }
                //Rellenador de x y o
                if(matrizl[(i+2)/4][(j+1)/2]==2 && i%8!=0 && j%4!=0){
                    matriz[i][j]=88;
                    matriz[i+2][j]=88;
                    matriz[i][j+1]=88;
                    matriz[i+2][j+1]=88;
                }
                if(matrizl[(i+2)/4][(j+1)/2]==3 && i%8!=0 && j%4!=0){
                    matriz[i][j]=79;
                    matriz[i+2][j]=79;
                    matriz[i][j+1]=79;
                    matriz[i+2][j+1]=79;
                }
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        //graficador del tablero
        system("cls");
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t TORTUNTITOS" << endl;
    cout << "\t--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout<<"Es el turno del jugador "<<k%2+1<<"      ";
        for(int i=0;i<=41;i++){
                printf("%c",matriz[i][0]);
            }
        cout<< "\t\tSCORE: " <<"  X = "<<puntaje1<<"    O = "<<puntaje2 << endl;
        for(int j=1;j<=20;j++){
            cout<<"                 ";
            for(int i=0;i<=41;i++){
                printf("%c",matriz[i][j]);
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }
        cout<<"Ingrese 00 para salir"<<endl;

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        //Inspector de posiciones
        int posicion_invalida=1;
        int confirmar_salir=0;
        do{
            cin.ignore();
            cin>>i1;
            cin>>j1;
      if(j1=='0' && i1=='0'){
        escribirArchivo();
      }
            v=matrizlogica(i1,j1);
            for(int jb=0;jb<=11;jb++){
            for(int ib=0;ib<=11;ib++){
                if(((i1==posicionletral[jb] && j1==posicionnumero[ib]) || (i1==posicionnumero[jb] && j1==posicionletral[ib]))){
                posicion_invalida=0;
                }}}
            if(posicion_invalida==1){
                cout<<"Ingrese una posicion valida"<<endl;
            }
            for(int jb=0;jb<=20;jb++){
            for(int ib=0;ib<=20;ib++){
                if((i1==posicionletral[jb] && j1==posicionnumero[ib]) || (i1==posicionnumero[jb] && j1==posicionletral[ib])){
                    if(i1==posicionletral[jb]){
                        if(matrizl[ib*2][jb*2-1]==1){
                            posicion_invalida=2;
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(matrizl[ib*2-1][jb*2]==1){
                            posicion_invalida=2;
              }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(posicion_invalida==2){
                cout<<"Posicion ya jugada, ingrese otra posicion"<<endl;
            }
            if(i1=='0' && j1=='0'){
                k=k+100;
                posicion_invalida=0;
            }
        }while(posicion_invalida!=0);
        valores=matrizlogica(i1,j1);

        //lineas de tabla logica
        int confirm=0;
        do{
        for(int jb=0;jb<=20;jb++){
            for(int ib=0;ib<=20;ib++){
                if((i1==posicionletral[jb] && j1==posicionnumero[ib]) || (i1==posicionnumero[jb] && j1==posicionletral[ib])){
                    if(i1==posicionletral[jb]){
                        matrizl[ib*2][jb*2-1]=1;
                        confirm=1;
                    }else{
                        matrizl[ib*2-1][jb*2]=1;
                        confirm=1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        }while(confirm=0);

        int pasounicob;

        if(pasounicob!=1){
        //bordes de la tabla valor=1
        for(int jb=0;jb<=20;jb++){
            for(int ib=0;ib<=20;ib++){
                if(ib==0 || jb==0 || ib==10 || jb==10){
                    matrizl[ib][jb]=1;
                }
            }
        }
        //puntos de la tabla logica
        for(int jb=0;jb<=20;jb++){
            for(int ib=0;ib<=20;ib++){
                if(ib%2==0 && jb%2==0){
                    matrizl[ib][jb]=8;
                }
            }
        }
        pasounicob=1;
        }

        //confirmador de 4 lineas completadas
        int ka=k;
        for(int jb=1;jb<=20;jb+=2){
            for(int ib=1;ib<=20;ib+=2){
                if(matrizl[ib-1][jb]==1 && matrizl[ib+1][jb]==1 && matrizl[ib][jb-1]==1 && matrizl[ib][jb+1]==1 && matrizl[ib][jb]==0 && k%2==1){
                    matrizl[ib][jb]=2;
                    ka=ka-1;
                }
                if(matrizl[ib-1][jb]==1 && matrizl[ib+1][jb]==1 && matrizl[ib][jb-1]==1 && matrizl[ib][jb+1]==1 && matrizl[ib][jb]==0 && k%2==0){
                    matrizl[ib][jb]=3;
                    ka=ka-1;
                }
            }
        }
        k=ka;

        //Puntajes
        int c1=0,c2=0;
        for(int jb=1;jb<=20;jb+=2){
            for(int ib=1;ib<=20;ib+=2){
                if(matrizl[ib][jb]==2){
                    c1+=1;
                    puntaje1=c1;
                    fichas[0].puntos=puntaje1;
                }
                if(matrizl[ib][jb]==3){
                    c2+=1;
                    puntaje2=c2;
                    fichas[1].puntos=puntaje2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void escribirArchivo(){
    ofstream archivo;
    archivo.open("TabladePuntuaciones.txt",ios::app);
    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout<<"No se puede abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }
    for(int i=0; i<2;i++)
    archivo << "\t" << fichas[i].nombre << "\t\t||\t    " << fichas[i].puntos << endl;
    archivo.close();
}

void leerArchivo(string opcion){
  ifstream archivo(opcion.c_str());
    char linea[128];
    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout<<"Error abrir el archivo"<<endl;
    }else{
        while(!archivo.eof()){
            archivo.getline(linea,sizeof(linea));
            cout<<linea<<endl;
        }
    }
    archivo.close();
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void titulo(){
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<""<<endl;
    cout<<"                     ...."<<endl;
    cout<<"              ..';;:cllllcc:;,'."<<endl;
    cout<<"           .,:lddddddddddddddddol:'."<<endl;
    cout<<"        .,coddddolc:;,,,,,;:codddddo:'"<<endl;
    cout<<"      .;lddddl:'..           ..,coddddc'"<<endl;
    cout<<"     'ldddoc'.                   .;loooo:."<<endl;
    cout<<"   .;odddl'                         ......"<<endl;
    cout<<"  .:dddo:."<<endl;
    cout<<"  ;dddd;                                                                                 '."<<endl;
    cout<<" .ldddc.        'dxxxxxxdxl.                    ':.                              .:.    ,Od.  .:."<<endl;
    cout<<" ,dddo'         .:cckWXdcc;.   .''..    .'. ....kMx..  .'.     .'.   '. .'''.   .kMk..  .c,  .xMk..    ..''.      .','."<<endl;
    cout<<" :dddl.             :N0,    .lO0kk00d'  oN0xOx:lXMKdo'.xNl    .xNo  :XKxxOKX0c .lXMKxo, :Xk..lKMKxo, 'd00kO0Ol. .d0kxkk;"<<endl;
    cout<<" :dddl.             :NK,   .xWk'  .dNO' oMXo'. .kMx.. .xMo    .xMo  cNNd...dNK, .xMx..  cWO. .xMk.. .ONd.  'kWx.;XXo,,' "<<endl;
    cout<<" ;dddo.             :NK,   '0Nc    ;XX; oMk.   .xMd   .xMd    .OMo  :N0'   ;XK;  dMd    cWO.  dMx.  ;XX;    cN0' ,oxO0O:"<<endl;
    cout<<" 'oddd;             :NK,    lXKl,':ONd. oMx.    dMO:,. oWKo;;cxNMd  cN0'   ;XK,  oWO:,. cNO.  oW0:,..dNO:,,lKNl.,c;';kWk"<<endl;
    cout<<" .:dddo'            ,xd.     ,oxkkko;   :kc     .okOx' .cxOOkdcoO:  ,xo.   .dd.  .okOx' ,kl.  .okOx,  ;oxkkxo,  'oxxxxo'"<<endl;
    cout<<"  .ldddl'"<<endl;
    cout<<"   .ldddo;."<<endl;
    cout<<"    .:ddddl,.                     .,,,,;'."<<endl;
    cout<<"      'lddddl:'.               .,:odddoc."<<endl;
    cout<<"       .'coddddoc;,'.......',:coddddo:."<<endl;
    cout<<"          .;codddddddooooodddddddo:,."<<endl;
    cout<<"             .';:looodddddoolc:,.."<<endl;
    cout<<"                 ...,;;;;,'.."<<endl;
    system("color 3");
    Beep(1500,700);
    system("color 9");
    Beep(1100,700);
    system("color 8");
    Beep(900,700);
    system("color 2");
    Beep(800,700);
    system("color 1");
    Beep(700,700);
    system("color 4");
    Beep(600,700);
    system("color 3");
    Beep(500,700);
    system("color 5");
    Beep(400,700);
    system("color 2");
    Beep(300,700);
    system("color 7");
    Beep(200,700);
    system("color 0");
}
```

Comment: Las respuestas que además del código exponen una guía o explicación del mismo son mejor recibidas, recomiendo mucho leas [answer]

Comment: Además la pregunta versa sobre Java y tu estás respondiendo en otro lenguaje